# How is the resultant defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

In my lecture notes we have the following:

We have that $f(x, y), g(x, y) \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$

$$f(x,y)=a_0(y)+a_1(y)x+ \dots +a_n(y)x^n \\ g(x, y)=b_0(y)+b_1(y)x+ \dots +b_m(y)x^m$$

The resultant is defined in the following way:

$$Res(f,g)(y)=det\begin{bmatrix}
a_0(y) & a_1(y) & \dots  & a_n(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\ 
0 & a_0(y) & \dots  & a_{n-1}(y) & a_n(y) & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\ 
\dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots \\ 
0 & 0 & a_0(y) & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & a_n(y) \\ 
b_0(y) & b_1(y) & b_2(y) & \dots  & b_m(y) & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\ 
0 & b_0(y) & b_1(y) & \dots  & b_m(y) & \dots  & \dots  & 0 \\ 
\dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & b_0(y) & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & b_m(y)
\end{bmatrix}$$

I haven't understood how the resultant is defined.

For example when we have $f(x, y)=y^2+x^2$ and $g(x, y)=y+x$, we have that $a_0(y)=y^2, a_1(y)=0, a_2(y)=1, b_0(y)=y, b_1(y)=1$.

How do we create the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the matrix is given by:

$$\begin{pmatrix}y^2 & 0 & 1  \\
y & 1 & 0  \\ 
0 & y & 1 
\end{pmatrix} $$
In general, note that you have $m$ lines of $a$'s and $n$ lines of $b$'s and most importantly that the final result need to be and $(n+m) \times (n+m)$ matrix. Put differently, to the first line of $a$'s pad $m-1$ entries of $0$, and to the first line of $b$' pad $n-1$.

This matrix is called ["Sylvester matrix"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) which should lead you to further examples.

Comment: The number of lines of $a$'s is equal to the highest power of $g$ and the number of lines of $b$'s is equal to the highest power of $f$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes, the number of times the coeffcients of one polynomial are repeated  is the highest power/degree (in $x$) of the *other* polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The resultant is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 & 0 & 1\\
y & 1 & 0\\
0 & y & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since we need $m=1$ row of coefficients of $f$ and $n=2$ rows of coefficients of $g$.

Comment: The number of lines of $a$'s is equal to the highest power of $g$ and the number of lines of $b$'s is equal to the highest power of $f$. Have I understood it correctly?